# How to calculate total duration: Durationfield()

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am unable to calculate total time duration . Here Videos have durations, which is DurationField(). I am confusing about how to calculate total time duration from all videos.

```
Model

class VideoDetails(BaseModel, Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False)
    video_about_text = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False)
    duration = models.DurationField()
    video = models.OneToOneField(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CourseModuleVideos(Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    module_id = models.ForeignKey(CourseModule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Video(BaseModel, Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

view

z = CourseModuleVideos.objects.filter(module_id=o)
            for zo in z:
                print('o', zo.video_id)
                x = VideoDetails.objects.filter(video=zo.video_id).aggregate(sum('duration'))
                print(x.duration)
```

Thre is an error

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"
```

Give me a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you share the `CourseModuleVideos` model?

Comment: Furthermore please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: class CourseModuleVideos(Timestamps):
    module_id = models.ForeignKey(CourseModule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Please [edit] the question. with the `CourseModuleVideos` and `Video` model.

Comment: Can you explain where there is a `ForeignKey` from `VideoDetails` to `Video` or viced versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with a [**`Sum`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum), not with the [**<s>`sum`</s>** builtin function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). You thus can implement this with the `Sum`, and access the value in the dictionary with `x['duration']`

```
from django.db.models import Sum

# ⋮

x = VideoDetails.objects.filter(video=zo.video_id).aggregate(
    Sum('duration')
)
print(x['duration'])
```

This is however not very efficient, since you will calculate the duration of each `VideoDetails` separately, and thus for *N* videos, make *N* queries.

We can calculate the sum of the entire module with:

```
VideoDetails.objects.filter(
    video__coursemodulevideos__module_id=o
).aggregate(sum('duration'))['duration'] or timdelta()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information and help